# Make disk bootable while mounted on running VM

Tags: boot, virtualbox, mbr

So I used RSYNC to backup all the files from a VPS I have that runs on my providers platform to a local disk attached to a VM I have running here.  The disk where all the files went to is a separate drive (`/dev/sdb`) from the one the VM uses (`/dev/sda`) as my intention is to detach it from this VM and make it the boot disk on a new VM I will create using it.
Though RSYNC reported that some files were not copied, because the VPS itself was live when I did the backup, I looked through the backup and everything seems to be there, including the boot partition and `vmlinuz` & `initrd.img` symlinks.

Now I want to use this disk (`/dev/sdb`) to boot a fresh new VM, which would be a mirror of my Live VPS.  How can I make this disk bootable without erasing any of the data it contains so I can use it on the new VM I'm setting up?

When I created this disk, I partitioned it to use the entire disk, from Sector 1 to it's maximum, and then formatted the partition using `ext4`.  If the solution to my question requires a GPT partition to be inserted, I can easily create a new disk (`/dev/sdc`), partition it appropriately, and then copy the data to it. (Which is the basis of the partition map below.)

```
Partition       First Sector    Last Sector Name                  Label UUID    File System     Mount Point  Size   Used       Unused   Flags
/dev/sda1               2048           4095                                     grub2 core.img              1.0MB                       bios_grub
/dev/sda2               4096        1054719 EFI System Partition                fat32           /boot/efi/  513MB   6.27MB   506.73MB   boot,esp
/dev/sda3            1054720       20969471                                     ext4                     /  9.5GB    8.5GB  1018.44MB

/dev/sdb1               2048      167772159                                     ext4                         80GB  45.21GB    34.79GB

/dev/sdc1          ???    This is the drive I want to make bootable
```

My plan at the moment is to make the partition layout of `sdc` the same as `sda` except for the size of the 3rd partition.  I'm using `GParted` and `Disks` to configure this.

Comment: `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` optionally followed by `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` or whatever depending on your distro. This will not erase or touch any of your data.

Comment: So, where you have `sda` in your comment, I should use `sdc`?

Comment: I added the drive/partition details to my question.

Comment: I don't understand, I thought you had a **new VM** with a **single drive** *"Now I want to use this disk (/dev/sdb) to boot a fresh new VM, which would be a mirror of my Live VPS"*, now you're talking about **three drives** and a **physical PC**. I'm confused and out of this question. Please dismiss my previous comment.

Comment: I agree my original question didn't have the precision the current version has.  However, I did mention that I'm only using VMs here, and that three disks are involved.  Since I asked the question, I have been continuing to try and solve my own problem, and is the reason I am now putting more emphasis on the 3rd disk, as I don't think it is practical to shift the data on the 2nd disk to make room for the partition table and EFI partition that's needed to boot from the drive.